# How to allow only for dates that are equal and smaller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

Here is my code to find whether the two given dates are equal or not ..

It should allow if today is small or equal. and it should not allow if it is greater date.

```
var date = '10-11-2015';
var today = '11-11-2016'
alert(today)
alert(date)
if( today <= date )
{
    alert("small-or-equal-allow")
}
else
{
   alert("larger-not-allow")   
}
```

But its showing not working as expected for few days. What is the mistake and how can i fix it ?

Comment: convert the strings to dates then compare :-)

Comment: may i know how can i do that pls

Comment: 12-11-2015 > 11-11-2016 because first letter is higher value, change to dates as suggested by JonSG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not dates.  If you want the values to be treated as dates then you need to cast them as dates...

```js
var date = new Date('10-11-2015');
var today = new Date('11-11-2016');

if (today <= date) {
   alert("small-or-equal-allow");
}
else {
   alert("larger-not-allow");
}
```

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor is strongly discouraged as parsing of any format other than ISO 8601 is implementation dependent. Either a bespoke function (2 lines of code) or a library should be used.